# nixnote not working

Tags: evernote

I've installed `nixnote` (desktop client of `Evernote` for `Linux`) in my Ubuntu 12.04.
But while starting, it throws exception.
[Here](http://pastebin.com/KGVmiHet) is complete detail of the exception.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the nixnote is installed through `ppa:vincent-c/nevernote`, then the default directory of installation files will be `/usr/share/nixnote`.
Depending upon the installed `Java (32 bit or 64 bit)` on the system i.e 
 if  the system has `64 bit java` then remove

`/usr/share/nixnote/lib/qtjambi-linux32-4.5.2_01.jar` and
`/usr/share/nixnote/lib/qtjambi-linux32-gcc-4.5.2_01`

and if running `java is 32 bit` then remove

`/usr/share/nixnote/lib/qtjambi-linux64-4.5.2_01.jar` and
`/usr/share/nixnote/lib/qtjambi-linux64-gcc-4.5.2_01`

Also make sure that the `/tmp` directory is not mounted with `noexec`
If it then use following command to remount `/tmp` with `exec`

`#mount -o remount,exec /tmp`

thats it.